# Crashed client on a named pipe server and subsequent reconnect

Tags: c#, ipc

Evening,

I am writing this in the awareness that I am lacking a bit of fundamental understanding in named pipe server / client architecture and hope that somebody can help me. My goal is to have a server application that a client can connect to and in case the client crashes, a restart of the client application will allow for a reconnect to the server. Both applications run on the same machine.

Following scenario: I have a application/program that opens a named pipe server, like so

```
// Provide full access to the current user so more pipe instances can be created
PipeSecurity m_ps = new PipeSecurity();
m_ps.AddAccessRule(
    new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User, PipeAccessRights.FullControl,
    AccessControlType.Allow)
);
m_ps.AddAccessRule(
    new PipeAccessRule(
        new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null),
        PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow
    )
);
/// Init the pipe
LauncherPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("CommandPipe",
    PipeDirection.In,
    1000,
    PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
    PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
    1,
    1,
    m_ps);
```

In a separate thread of this program I then wait for a connection from the client

```
...
LauncherPipeServerWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
LauncherPipeServerWorker.DoWork += ServerPipeHandling_DoWork;
LauncherPipeServerWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

private void ServerPipeHandling_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    LauncherPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
    /// React to incoming messages
}
```

I can run this connection and it works, doing what it should. The interesting bit comes, when the application running the client crashes. Upon a restart of that application, the client is unable to reconnect to the server.

Of the solutions that I found, I wasn't really able to comprehend if and how they could solve my problem. My understanding was that the server object can accept one or multiple incoming clients and send and receive messages from all of them. So in case my client crashes, I just restart it and it can connect and register as a new client. But it doesn't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an exception is thrown but yo don't see it because it's a worker thread; you have to handle it in a try/catch/finally block.

Most likely you're useing a `StreamReader` to read the pipe contents and then dispose of it before calling `.WaitForConnection` again. Disposing of a `StreamReader` also closes its underlying stream (unless the `leaveOpen` ctor parameter was true). Then the next call to `.WaitForConnection` will throw but it might go unnoticed, leaving the impression that the waiting has begun.